# Multiple textboxfor, same model. ValidationMessageFor not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor, validationmessage

I'm not getting all my textboxes's validation to work. Only while using "one" at a time.
I'm trying to use the same model property for of my variations. Does anyone know a solution to this, or a better way of doing this?

```
@Html.Hidden("AggKPIID", item.AggKPIID)
@if (item.Värde.ToString() == "-1" || item.Värde.ToString() == "0")
{                   
  @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Värde, new { Value = "", Name = "Värde", @class = "kpiTextbox kpiTextbox-edit", @id = "tb"+Id })
  <br />
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Värde)
}
else
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Värde, new { @class = "kpiTextbox kpiTextbox-edit", @id = "tb" + Id })
  <br />
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Värde)
}    
@Html.Hidden("Tidsperiod", item.Tidsperiod)
@Html.Hidden("Id", Id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown the complete code but it appears you are rendering this in a `foreach` loop. This will generate duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and `name` attributes so it wont post back to your collection anyway.  Because the name attributes are all the same, the associated validation errors cannot be matched up. Change you view to use a `for` loop (the model needs to be `IList<T>` or alternatively you can use a custom `EditorTemplate`. Note I don't understand what you `if` statement is doing (it makes no sense) and if you want to change the value of `Värde` to an empty string if its value is `0` or `-1`, then you do that in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

```
for(int i = 0, i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[0].AggKPIID)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[0].Värde, new { @class = "kpiTextbox kpiTextbox-edit" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[0].Värde)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[0].Tidsperiod)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[0].Id)
}
```

and always used strongly types helpers and don't try to update the `name` attribute (not that `new { Name = "Värde" }` would do anything anyway)

Comment: Hey . You're right about me using a foreach. I get what you are saying. This is from a partialview, inside a table. And This part is just for the textbox. About the strongly typed helpers, I believe I chaged them to fit my update viewmodel more. Since it was sent item.Värde, and The VM could only pick up Värde.

Comment: Your going to have problems if your using partial views to render controls in a form for postback to model that is a collection or contains a property which is a collection. You haven't posted enough code to be sure, but you should always use an `EditorTemplate` or a `for` loop for collections to ensure the controls are correctly named with indexers (`name="[0].AggKPIID"`, `name="[1].AggKPIID"` etc.)

Comment: This is inside a Ajax beginform. And Im not updating any view. Just using onsuccess and onfailure. So my action returns Json. I use jquery to show an "ok" image if update goes well.  But youre right :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define it only once

```
@{var attrs = null;}
@if (item.Värde.ToString() == "-1" || item.Värde.ToString() == "0")
{
    attrs = new { Value = "", @class = "kpiTextbox kpiTextbox-edit", @id = "tb" + Id };
}
else
{
    attrs = new { @class = "kpiTextbox kpiTextbox-edit", @id = "tb" + Id };
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Värde, attrs)
<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Värde)
```

I also don't recommend setting `Name`.

Comment: Thanks man. It would work fine with your solution, if i wasnt using a foreach. Me not giving enough info :)